# Ajax success/error message only displaying once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have created a form using `php` `ajax` and `JavaScript`.

With ajax I successfully managed to display an error/success message while staying on the same page.

It works alright if I use `console.log` to display the error/success message.

But I don't want to display the error message on the `console.log`

so this is what I did:

```
 $('form.form-style-4').on('submit', function() {
     var that = $(this),
         url = that.attr('action'),
         method = that.attr('method'),
         data = {};
     that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
         var that = $(this),
             name = that.attr('name'),
             value = that.val();

         data[name] = value;
     });

     $.ajax({
         url: url,
         type: method,
         data: data,
         success: function(response) {

             console.log(response);
             $('#success-message').html(response);
             setTimeout(function() {
                 $('#success-message').fadeOut('slow');
             }, 3000);



         }
     });

     return false;


 });
```

As you can see I created a div called `#success-message` the reponse is displayed in this div.

My problem now is It only shows the error or success message just once, unless I reload the page.

So my first idea was to reload the entire page every time someone clicks on submit, with javascript like this:

```
 setTimeout(function() {
                 window.location.reload(1);
             }, 2000);
```

But I don't think that is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to show your message `success-message` first

```
$('#success-message').html(response).show();
```